# Getting rid of grouping field

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

Is there a safe way to not have to group by a field when using an aggregate in another field? Here is my example

```
SELECT 

C.CustomerName
,D.INDUSTRY_CODE

,CASE WHEN D.INDUSTRY_CODE IN ('003','004','005','006','007','008','009','010','017','029')
    THEN 'PM'
    WHEN UPPER(CustomerName) = 'ULINE INC'
    THEN 'ULINE'
    ELSE 'DR'
    END AS BU

,ISNULL((SELECT  SUM(GrossAmount) 
where CONVERT(date,convert(char(8),InvoiceDateID )) between DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) and DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())),0) [PREVIOUS YEAR GROSS]

FROM factMargins A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dimDate B ON A.InvoiceDateID = B.DateId
LEFT OUTER JOIN dimCustomer C ON A.CustomerID = C.CustomerId
LEFT OUTER JOIN CRCDATA.DBO.CU10 D ON D.CUST_NUMB = C.CustomerNumber

GROUP BY 
C.CustomerName,D.INDUSTRY_CODE
,A.InvoiceDateID

order by CustomerName
```

before grouping I was only getting 984 rows but after grouping by the A.InvoiceDateId field I am getting over 11k rows. The rows blow up since there are multiple invoices per customer. Min and Max wont work since then it will pull data incorrectly. Would it be best to let my application (crystal) get rid of the extra lines? Usually I like to have my base data be as close as possible to how the report will layout if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving the reference to InvoiceDateID to within an aggregate function, rather than within a selected subquery's WHERE clause.

In Oracle, here's an example:

```
with TheData as (
select 'A' customerID, 25 AMOUNT , trunc(sysdate) THEDATE from dual union
select 'B' customerID, 35 AMOUNT , trunc(sysdate-1) THEDATE from dual union
select 'A' customerID, 45 AMOUNT , trunc(sysdate-2) THEDATE from dual union
select 'A' customerID, 11000 AMOUNT , trunc(sysdate-3) THEDATE from dual union
select 'B' customerID, 12000 AMOUNT , trunc(sysdate-4) THEDATE from dual union
select 'A' customerID, 15000 AMOUNT , trunc(sysdate-5) THEDATE from dual)
select 
    CustomerID, 
    sum(amount) as "AllRevenue" 
    sum(case when thedate<sysdate-3 then amount else 0 end) as "OlderRevenue", 
from thedata
group by customerID;
```

Output:

```
CustomerID | AllRevenue | OlderRevenue
A | 26070 | 26000
B | 12035 | 12000
```

This says:

- For each customerID
- I want the sum of all amounts
- and I want the sum of amounts earlier than 3 days ago